# Having troubles with cvFindContours and cvSnakeImage

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm using the following code to find contours and running the snake algorith:

```
#include "cv.h" 
#include "opencv2\objdetect\objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\nonfree\nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2\legacy\legacy.hpp"
#include "highgui.h" 
using namespace cv;

void readme();

/** @function main */
Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 20;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);
int ialpha = 20;
int ibeta=20; 
int igamma=20; 
IplImage *image = 0 ;

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void* );
int main() 
{ 
    for (int fcount=1;fcount<52;fcount++){
        if(image) cvReleaseImage(&image);
        char filename[256];
        sprintf(filename,"C:\\OIM\\PersonDetectionResults\\original_frames\\image%d.jpg",fcount);

        image=cvLoadImage(filename);
        IplImage *im_gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
        cvCvtColor(image,im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);

        // Do some Edge detection
        IplImage* out = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(im_gray), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 
        cvCanny(im_gray, out, 10, 20, 3);

        /*cvNamedWindow( "Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        cvShowImage("Image", out);
        cvWaitKey(0);*/


        IplImage *original_image=cvCloneImage(im_gray);
        /// Find contours
        CvSeq* contours = 0;
        CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

        cvFindContours( out, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), 
            CV_RETR_LIST , CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

        if(!contours) return -1 ; 
        int length = contours->total;   
        if(length<3) continue ; 
        CvPoint* point = new CvPoint[length]; 

        CvSeqReader reader;
        CvPoint pt= cvPoint(0,0);;  
        CvSeq *contour2=contours;   

        cvStartReadSeq(contour2, &reader);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM(pt, reader);
            point[i]=pt;
        }
        cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);


        float alpha=ialpha/100.0f; 
        float beta=ibeta/100.0f; 
        float gamma=igamma/100.0f; 


        CvSize size; 
        size.width=3; 
        size.height=3; 
        CvTermCriteria criteria; 
        criteria.type=CV_TERMCRIT_ITER; 
        criteria.max_iter=1000; 
        criteria.epsilon=0.1; 
        cvSnakeImage( out, point,length,&alpha,&beta,&gamma,CV_VALUE,size,criteria,0 ); 

        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            int j = (i+1)%length;
            cvLine( original_image, point[i],point[j],CV_RGB( 0, 255, 0 ),1,8,0 ); 
        }
        delete []point;

        sprintf(filename,"C:\\Test\\image%d.jpg",fcount);
        cvSaveImage(filename, &(IplImage(*original_image)));
        /*cvNamedWindow( "Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        cvShowImage("Image", im_gray);
        cvWaitKey(0);*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the original image:
[image]
And here is the result:
[image]

As you can see, no contour is drawn.

I think that the problem is that I'm getting very few contours from cvFindContours, is there any method of lowering the thresholds to get more contours?

Thanks in advance,

Gil.

Answer (score 0):

[findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/master/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) tends to 'eat up' the image ( look at the 1st note there )

if you need the binary image for further processing, you have to clone() it before feeding it into findContours()

Comment: Thanks @berak. How do I clone a IplImage? And why do I get so few contours from cvFindContours?

Comment: 1.: mat.clone() in c++, [cloneImage()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#IplImage*%20cvCloneImage(const%20IplImage*%20image)) in c . 2.: you need a *binary* image as input to findContours, so an additional threshold, compare, Canny or Sobel pass is needed between grayscale and findcontours

Comment: why did you go over to the 'dark side' ? (pun intended), and start using the *dreaded* c-api, and plunder the legacy ? there's probably good reasons, that cvSnakeImage ended up there.

Comment: Hi @berak, that's because I have to use the snake algorithm. I wish it wasn't in C :/

Comment: Hi @berak, I added thresholding using Canny, but I'm still getting very few contours (I edited the question). Do you know why it happens?

Thanks,Gil.

Comment: probably your Canny params are bad, try threshold(src,dst, 100, 255,0 ); instead (sorry for the c++ answer, but you'll get the picture)

Comment: Thanks @berak, I tried   cvThreshold(im_gray,im_gray,100,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY); 

but I'm still getting very few contours (less than 10). Do you have any other ideas?

Thanks,
Gil.

Comment: sorry, no idea now. but my snake experiment [here](https://github.com/berak/opencv_smallfry/blob/master/snake.cpp) turned out not really nice (algo there seems to have a problem with concave things)

Comment: aww, sorry mixed up 3.0 and 2.4 above, reload if interested